# iPhone - Is there a way of adjusting the screen brightness in a device-level

Tags: ios

I'm aware of this post titled "[iPhone - Is there a way of adjusting the screen brightness](http://iphone%20-%20Is%20there%20a%20way%20of%20adjusting%20the%20screen%20brightness)," and in fact, I've checked the official Apple API [UIScreen](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006903-CH3-SW19), but this can only change the brightness within one app, and my question is something different, though I think very likely there's no such a way to do that: Is it possible to change the global screen brightness? By that I mean to use code to adjust this brightness bar:

[image]

Though my intuition tells me probably Apple is not happy with doing this and I probably will get rejected by AppStore, can somebody confirm that?

Comment: No you can't and of course users don´t wont some app to change their global settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Apple doesn't allow any apps to access global screen settings. [On this Q&A page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1751/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013391), they write:

> It is not the developer's responsibility to restore the brightness,
>   and as you may have seen you cannot set the brightness once the app
>   leaves the foreground. This behavior is by design.

Answer (score 1):

They will reject it. Before have app do this and now they remove from AppStore. You can reference to this: [Flux app](https://justgetflux.com/ios.html)